Android ViewModelProvider.Factory CreationExtras. Why use it?
I am having a hard time understanding the need to use the CreationExtras for the custom ViewModelProvider.Factory.
I understand you need to define the factory if you want to use some custom logic while initializing the viewmodel,but what I have always done is to pass my arguments directly to the constructor of the factory, and then use them while instantiating the view model. What does the CreationExtras object achieve? Why not just pass the arguments directly to the factory constructor?
This is Google's example on how to use it:
class MyViewModel(
        private val myRepository: MyRepository,
        private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
    ) : ViewModel() {

        // ViewModel logic
        // ...

        // Define ViewModel factory in a companion object
        companion object {

            val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                override fun <T : ViewModel> create(
                    modelClass: Class<T>,
                    extras: CreationExtras
                ): T {
                    // Get the Application object from extras
                    val application = checkNotNull(extras[APPLICATION_KEY])
                    // Create a SavedStateHandle for this ViewModel from extras
                    val savedStateHandle = extras.createSavedStateHandle()

                    return MyViewModel(
                        (application as MyApplication).myRepository,
                        savedStateHandle
                    ) as T
                }
            }
        }
    }

And what I am used to do is creating a custom class that implements the ViewModelProvider.Factory interface and take those arguments in the constructor instead: something like
class MyFactory(val repository: MyRepository){
 // use repository when creating instance of VM
}


The CreationExtras provides you a SavedStateHandle, which allows to save and restore UI state across process death.
